# How to verify visibility of a button in python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to verify if a button element is not displayed on the UI. The code is written in Java script by the developer. I am writing automated scripts using Selenium Webdriver and Python. If the button is enabled, I can see `li` tag added in the code. But if a button is disabled, the code for the button disappears when I am inspecting it from the UI (F12->Inspect Elements).

Currently, my code looks like this

```
def delete_btn_disabled(self):        
        try:
            button = self.driver.find_element(*Elements.delete_btn).is_displayed()
            if button is True:
                return True
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
```

And my test case is following:

```
        if spage.delete_btn_disabled() is False:
            print("Test passed")
        else:
            print("Test failed")
```

Is there a better way to handle this? Throwing `NoSuchElementException` looks a bit dirty (please correct me if I am wrong) and I have to handle this type of code for other test cases as well.

I have googled this but can't seem to find a correct solution for this problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.find_elements()` to see if the element exists. If the returned list is empty, you know the element is not present (or displayed). If it's not empty, check `.is_displayed()` on the first element.

```
def delete_btn_disabled(self):        
    button = self.driver.find_elements(*Elements.delete_btn)
    if button:
        return button[0].is_displayed()
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

`is_displayed` DOES NOT equal to `is_visible`.

You still cannot be sure the button is visible from the UI, even it is displayed somewhere outside the screen. So it is still NOT clickable.

Comment: You can detect clickability using `EC.element_to_be_clickable` with a wait

Answer (score 0):

Selenium manages these conditions best using expectations and waits. This will ensure that if it cannot meet your expectations it will also time out. You can use a wait for visibility using the `visibility_of` convenience method like so:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of((By.ID, 'id_1')))
```

There's a full list of expectation methods [here.](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)